# C++ header and implementation code in C program

Tags: c++, c

I have a header and an implementation code written in C++, they load sprites, set position, detect collision, etc., but when I call them in the C program the compiler throws me a bunch of errors of the same in the header file when declaring the class and in the .c file, when declaring an instance of the class, the error is this:

```
error: expected  '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '_attribute_' before Cframe, Csprite,
fnave, fmalo, nave, malo...
```

And in the functions that i use this variables, also sends me the error of

```
'***' undeclares( first use in this function)...
```

Can someone tell me the error I'm making, or is it that you cannot use C++ headers and implementation files in C programs?

P.S. I put the C code at the end, I don't know if that helps xD

csprite.h

```
#ifndef CSPRITE_H_
#define CSPRITE_H_
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
// CFrame representa un frame independiente de un sprite.
class CFrame {
public:
SDL_Surface *img;
void load(char *path);
void unload();
};
// La clase CSprite está formada por un array de frames;
class CSprite {
private:
int posx,posy;
int estado;
int nframes;
int cont;
public:
CFrame *sprite;
CSprite(int nf);
CSprite();
void finalize();
void addframe(CFrame frame);
void selframe(int nf);
int frames() {return cont;}
void setx(int x) {posx=x;}
void sety(int y) {posy=y;}
void addx(int c) {posx+=c;}
void addy(int c) {posy+=c;}
int getx() {return posx;}
int gety() {return posy;}
int getw() {return sprite[estado].img->w;}
int geth() {return sprite[estado].img->h;}
void draw(SDL_Surface *superficie);
int colision(CSprite sp);
};
#endif /* CSPRITE_H_ */
```

csprite.cpp

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include "csprite.h"
// Sprite Class implementation
void CFrame::load( char *path) {
    img=SDL_LoadBMP(path);
    // Asignamos el color transparente al color rojo.
    SDL_SetColorKey(img,SDL_SRCCOLORKEY|SDL_RLEACCEL, SDL_MapRGB(img->format,255,0,0));
    img=SDL_DisplayFormat(img);
}
void CFrame::unload(){
    SDL_FreeSurface(img);
}
CSprite::CSprite(int nf) {
    sprite=new CFrame[nf];
    nframes=nf;
    cont=0;
}
CSprite::CSprite() {
    int nf=1;
    sprite=new CFrame[nf];
    nframes=nf;
    cont=0;
}
void CSprite::finalize() {
    int i;
    for (i=0 ; i<=nframes-1 ; i++)
        sprite[i].unload();
}
void CSprite::addframe(CFrame frame) {
    if (cont<nframes) {
        sprite[cont]=frame;
        cont++;
    }
}
void CSprite::selframe(int nf) {
    if (nf<=nframes) {
        estado=nf;
    }
}
void CSprite::draw(SDL_Surface *superficie) {
    SDL_Rect dest;
    dest.x=posx;
    dest.y=posy;
    SDL_BlitSurface(sprite[estado].img,NULL,superficie,&dest);
}
int CSprite::colision(CSprite sp) {
    int w1,h1,w2,h2,x1,y1,x2,y2;
    w1=getw(); // ancho del sprite1
    h1=geth(); // altura del sprite1
    w2=sp.getw(); // ancho del sprite2
    h2=sp.geth(); // alto del sprite2
    x1=getx(); // pos. X del sprite1
    y1=gety(); // pos. Y del sprite1
    x2=sp.getx(); // pos. X del sprite2
    y2=sp.gety(); // pos. Y del sprite2
    if (((x1+w1)>x2)&&((y1+h1)>y2)&&((x2+w2)>x1)&&((y2+h2)>y1)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

game.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "csprite.h"

SDL_Surface *screen;
CFrame fnave;
CFrame fmalo;
CSprite nave(1);
CSprite malo(1);
SDL_Rect rectangulo;
SDL_Joystick *joystick;
int joyx, joyy;
int done=0;
// estructura que contiene la información
// de nuestro avión
struct minave {
    int x,y;
} jugador;
// Estructura que contiene información
// del avión enemigo
struct naveenemiga {
    int x,y;
} enemigo;
// Dibuja los esprites en la pantalla
void DrawScene(SDL_Surface *screen) {
    // borramos el avión dibujado
    // en el frame anterior
    rectangulo.x=nave.getx();
    rectangulo.y=nave.gety();
    rectangulo.w=nave.getw();
    rectangulo.h=nave.geth();
    SDL_FillRect(screen,&rectangulo,SDL_MapRGB(screen->format,0,0,0));
    // dibuja avión
    nave.setx(jugador.x);
    nave.sety(jugador.y);
    nave.draw(screen);
    // Dibuja enemigo
    malo.setx(enemigo.x);
    malo.sety(enemigo.y);
    malo.draw(screen);
    // ¿ha colisionado con la nave?
    if (malo.colision(nave) == TRUE) {
        done=1;
    }
    // Mostramos todo el frame
    SDL_Flip(screen);
}
// Inicializamos estados
void inicializa() {
    jugador.x=300;
    jugador.y=300;
    enemigo.x=100;
    enemigo.y=100;
}
void finaliza() {
    // finalizamos los sprites
    nave.finalize();
    malo.finalize();
    // cerramos el joystick
    if (SDL_JoystickOpened(0)) {
        SDL_JoystickClose(joystick);
    }
}
// Preparamos los esprites
int InitSprites() {
    fnave.load("minave.bmp");
    nave.addframe(fnave);
    fmalo.load("nave.bmp");
    malo.addframe(fmalo);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Event event;
    Uint8 *keys;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK) < 0) {
        printf("No se pudo iniciar SDL: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,24,SDL_HWSURFACE);
    if (screen == NULL) {
        printf("No se puede inicializar el modo gráfico: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    atexit(SDL_Quit);
    inicializa();
    InitSprites();
    while (done == 0) {
        // dibujamos el frame
        DrawScene(screen);
        // consultamos el estado del teclado
        keys=SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
        // consultamos el estado del joystick
        SDL_JoystickUpdate();
        joyx = SDL_JoystickGetAxis(joystick, 0);
        joyy = SDL_JoystickGetAxis(joystick, 1);
        if ((keys[SDLK_UP] || joyy < -10) && (jugador.y > 0)) 
            {jugador.y=jugador.y-(5);}
        if ((keys[SDLK_DOWN] || joyy > 10) && (jugador.y < 460)) 
            {jugador.y=jugador.y+(5);}
        if ((keys[SDLK_LEFT] || joyx < -10) && (jugador.x > 0)) 
            {jugador.x=jugador.x-(5);}
        if ((keys[SDLK_RIGHT] || joyx > 10) && (jugador.x < 620)) 
            {jugador.x=jugador.x+(5);}
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {done=1;}
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN || event.type == SDL_JOYBUTTONDOWN) {
                if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
                    done=1;
                }
            }
        }
     }
    finaliza();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The file you have called `game.c` isn't even a C program. It's full of C++! For example, `rectangulo.x=nave.getx();` is a C++ method call.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot use your C++ header file in a C program, because your C++ header file uses C++ language features (like classes).

You can use a header file in both C and C++ programs if and only if the header file uses only those language features that are supported by both C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot (easily) call C++ code from C code, meaning that you're not supposed to do it : they are different languages. On the other hand, you can call C code from C++ code, as it's a supported feature of C++.

You should compile your `game.c` file in c++ ; this should be easy enough as C is mostly a subset of C++.

Rename your `game.c`to `game.cpp` and go ahead.

Comment: Compiling C with C++ may not be easy, because C++ is much more pedantic than C in some aspects, and may fail the compilation. But it may be for the best, because things C++ won't compile are bad practice in C, and you better fix them anyway.

Comment: @ugoren, good points usually, but look at `game.c`. It's actually full of C++ :-) This question doesn't make sense any more - there are method calls in `game.c`!

Answer (score 0):

Prefix all in your C functions and variables with `extern "C"` and compile it in C++

You can even do something like this in your game.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "csprite.h"

extern "C" {

SDL_Surface *screen;
CFrame fnave;
CFrame fmalo;
CSprite nave(1);
CSprite malo(1);
SDL_Rect rectangulo;
SDL_Joystick *joystick;
int joyx, joyy;
int done=0;
// estructura que contiene la información
// de nuestro avión
struct minave {
int x,y;
} jugador;
// Estructura que contiene información
// del avión enemigo
struct naveenemiga {
int x,y;
} enemigo;
// Dibuja los esprites en la pantalla
void DrawScene(SDL_Surface *screen) {
// borramos el avión dibujado
// en el frame anterior
rectangulo.x=nave.getx();
rectangulo.y=nave.gety();
rectangulo.w=nave.getw();
rectangulo.h=nave.geth();
SDL_FillRect(screen,&rectangulo,SDL_MapRGB(screen->format,0,0,0));
// dibuja avión
nave.setx(jugador.x);
nave.sety(jugador.y);
nave.draw(screen);
// Dibuja enemigo
malo.setx(enemigo.x);
malo.sety(enemigo.y);
malo.draw(screen);
// ¿ha colisionado con la nave?
if (malo.colision(nave) == TRUE) {
done=1;
}
// Mostramos todo el frame
SDL_Flip(screen);
}
// Inicializamos estados
void inicializa() {
jugador.x=300;
jugador.y=300;
enemigo.x=100;
enemigo.y=100;
}
void finaliza() {
    // finalizamos los sprites
nave.finalize();
malo.finalize();
// cerramos el joystick
if (SDL_JoystickOpened(0)) {
SDL_JoystickClose(joystick);
}
}
// Preparamos los esprites
int InitSprites() {
fnave.load("minave.bmp");
nave.addframe(fnave);
fmalo.load("nave.bmp");
malo.addframe(fmalo);
return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
SDL_Event event;
Uint8 *keys;
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK) < 0) {
printf("No se pudo iniciar SDL: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
return 1;
}
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,24,SDL_HWSURFACE);
if (screen == NULL) {
printf("No se puede inicializar el modo gráfico: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
return 1;
}
atexit(SDL_Quit);
inicializa();
InitSprites();
while (done == 0) {
// dibujamos el frame
DrawScene(screen);
// consultamos el estado del teclado
keys=SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
// consultamos el estado del joystick
SDL_JoystickUpdate();
joyx = SDL_JoystickGetAxis(joystick, 0);
joyy = SDL_JoystickGetAxis(joystick, 1);
if ((keys[SDLK_UP] || joyy < -10) && (jugador.y > 0)) {jugador.y=jugador.y-(5);}
if ((keys[SDLK_DOWN] || joyy > 10) && (jugador.y < 460)) {jugador.y=jugador.y+(5);}
if ((keys[SDLK_LEFT] || joyx < -10) && (jugador.x > 0)) {jugador.x=jugador.x-(5);}
if ((keys[SDLK_RIGHT] || joyx > 10) && (jugador.x < 620)) {jugador.x=jugador.x+(5);}
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {done=1;}
if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN || event.type == SDL_JOYBUTTONDOWN) {
if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
done=1;
}
}
}
}
finaliza();
return 0;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, the easiest thing is to rename `game.c` to `game.cpp` and just compile everything in C++. I just hope you haven't used too many C-specific extensions.

If you do need to compile a C++ header in C, you'll need to do the following:

(community-wiki, as this list is getting out of hand. Please help (or downvote this to oblivion!))

- rename every `class` to a `struct`. Classes and Structs are basically the same in C++, the only difference is that struct elements start off `public` by default.
- you need to hide the C++ specific stuff, like method declarations, by surrounding them in `#ifdef __cplusplus` and `#endif`
- convert `struct X { ... };` to `typedef struct { ... } X;`, because otherwise C code expects every such type to be prefixed by `struct`.
- no virtual methods are allowed (even if you don't actually do any inheritance, you must strictly avoid virtual methods).
- The c++ compiler will have to be told which of its functions are to be accesible by C. See the other answers about `extern "C"`
- .. anything else ?

(In short, it's a dangerous nightmare.)

Comment: Thanks everyone, i try to compile and one warning appear, but i think ill change everything so i can use it in c, at least, that is what im going to try xD